# Elasticsearch aggregate by field prefix

Tags: elasticsearch

I have data entries of the form

```
{
   "id": "ABCxxx",
   // Other fields
}
```

Where `ABC` is a unique identifier that defines the "type" of this record. (For example a user would be `USR1234...`, an image would be `IMG1234...`)

I want to get a list of all the different types of records that I have in my ES. So in essence I want to do a sort by `id` but only looking at the first three characters of the id.

This doesn't work obviously, because it sorts by `id` (so `USR123` is different than `USR456`):

```
{
    "fields": ["id"],
    "aggs": {
        "group_by_id": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "id"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I write this query?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the painless scripting language to get this accomplished.

```
{
    "fields": ["id"],
    "aggs": {
        "group_by_id": {
            "terms": {
                "script" : {
                    "inline": "doc['id'].substring(0,3)",
                    "lang": "painless"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

More info [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-script). Please note that the syntax for the substring method may not be exactly right.

Comment: :( my server doesn't allow that `script_lang not supported`

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: You need to explicitly enable scripting https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by **paqash** already that the same can be achieved via script but I would suggest an alternate of storing "type" as a different field altogether in your schema.

For eg.

```
USR1234 : {id:"USR1234", type:"USR"}
IMG1234 : {id:"USR1234", type:"IMG"}
```

This would avoid unnecessary complications in scripting and keep your query interface clean.